# I cannot routes cache when Laravel File Manager in routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I cannot use route:cache in my Laravel app when Laravel File Manager in my routes.

My routes setting:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'role:owner|admin']], function () { \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes(); });
```

Then my error when i use route:cache in terminal
[terminal screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DhKI.png)

Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `use_package_routes` inside `config/lfm` it will solve your problem.